# Rails - NoMethodError undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm getting the above error in my model. Here's the model code -

**Booking.rb**

```
    class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :event, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

    before_validation :set_default_values_to_greater_than_or_equal_to_zero

    def set_default_values_to_greater_than_or_equal_to_zero
        self.quantity >= 1
        self.total_amount >= 0  
        self.event.price >= 1    unless self.event.is_free
    end

    def reserve(stripe_token)
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        self.valid?

        # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
        #self.total_amount = booking.quantity * event.price

                # Free events don't need to do anything special
                if event.is_free?
                save!

                # Paid events should charge the customer's card
                else

                    begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price * self.quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                end
            end 
        #end
    end
end
```

The error code is thrown on this line -

```
self.quantity >= 1
```

I believe this is because of the default value (or lack of one) on this particular column/attribute. What is the correct process to correct this in migrations? Do I conduct a change_column_null migration or change_column_default ?

This is my table -

```
 create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "stripe_token"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "total_amount"
    t.string   "stripe_charge_id"
  end
```

As is evident, there is nothing set for quantity (nor total_amount). I've tried to correct this with the before_validation callback and method below this but they don't appear to be working. I believe the migration is the only way to solve this, am I correct?

This is my controller code, is there anything I need to put in here?

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
 class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user


end

def create

    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

        if 
            @booking.reserve(booking_params['stripe_token'])
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end
end


private

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
end
```

end

Comment: try this, to rescue exception
self.try(:quantity) >= 1

Comment: you say "set" quantity, but ">=" is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator.  What are you trying to achieve in `set_default_values_to_greater_than_or_equal_to_zero` this method? Also, I believe that method should be a private method, not a public one.

Comment: I'm trying to give quantity and total_amount a default value so I don't get the above error. In addition, if you note further down I want a user to be able to add a number of spaces when they book onto an event. So one space costs £10 but they want to book, say, 5 spaces, therefore they would need to pay £50 so total_amount = event.price * quantity (number of spaces required)

Comment: You can define a default right in your migration if you wish. `t.integer  "quantity", default: 8`

Answer (score 0):

If `set_default_values_to_greater_than_or_equal_to_zero` was an attempt to set a default for those attributes change `>=` to `=` because `>=` is an evaluation operator which will return `true` or `false`.  If you go this route, I would suggest to make that a private method.

If you want to make a migration instead, to set defaults on the database level, (which I would favor over a before validation callback),

`change_column_default(:bookings, :quantity, 1)`

or

`change_column :bookings, :quantity, :integer, :default => 1`

See:

[change column default](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default)

[change column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column)

As is noted in the change_column_default page comments, change column is the preferred way to do this

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend I do the migration for total_amount too? This also appears to have no default value set in the bookings table.

Comment: Yes, and I would remove that callback and method.  If that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I've done the migration but now the error I'm getting is 'Amount must be at least 30 pence'. Might be going off tangent here but is that to do with the amount section of stripe? (It's highlighting that line from my model, as above).

Comment: Yeah, it's probably adding that error on this line `errors.add(:base, e.message)`

Comment: Look into what this is doing `Stripe::CardError`